# Get field value from form and pass to web part list view filter

Tags: web-part, list-view, filter, form

In SharePoint 2016, I have created an edit form with a web part in the footer area that displays list data. I would like to grab the value from the field named Start Day and then use that value to filter the list view used on the web part. So, if the Start Date is 1/11/2019, I'd like to only bring in other items that have a Start Date to 1/11/2019.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using SharePoint OOTB web parts, you need use below webparts in such cases:

1. List web part(App web part)
2. SharePoint List Filter web part(or HTML form filter web part if you want to give hard coded date values in your dropdown)

**Steps**:

1. Add list web part from which you want to bring the data.
2. Add sharepoint list filter web part and select the StartDate column and its list by editing web part properties.
3. Connect these two web parts and use StartDate column to make the connection.

**References**

1. [Use SharePoint List Filter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/use-sharepoint-list-filter-in-sharepoint-2013/).
2. [Connect a Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f).